# Add methods to controllers

Tags: grails, metaprogramming

In a Grails application I would like to add a foo() method to all my controller classes. I know that I can do this inside a plugin's doWithDynamicMethods closure using code like:

```
application.controllerClasses.toList()*.metaClass*.foo = { println 'foo called' }
```

However, I don't want to create a plugin just for this purpose. Is there anywhere else I can do this. I suspect it might be possible within the `init` closure of `BootStrap.groovy`, but I don't know how to get access to the `GrailsApplication` instance in this closure.

Thanks,
Don

Comment: why not write a plugin? this is the perfect type of usecase for a plugin. you dont have to release it, nor does it have to be a large plugin. 
modularizing an app via plugins is a great grails idiom that you should follow if you can.

Answer (score 2):

```
def grailsApplication = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationHolder.application
```

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked a long time ago, so my answer might not have been possible back then - but now it's April 2014.  This code shows the most straightforward way of adding a method to all your controllers (from within `BootStrap.init`):

```
grailsApplication.controllerClasses.each { controllerClass ->
    if (controllerClass.clazz.name.contains("org.idurkan.foo")) {
        controllerClass.metaClass.respondError = { String message, int status = 404 ->
            response.status = status
            render([errorMessage: message] as JSON)
        }
    }
}
```

1. In BootStrap.groovy, inject grailsApplication like this: `def grailsApplication`
2. Make a call like mine above, substituting your own package name - to avoid messing around with plugins' classes.
3. Now in any controller you can use the `repondError` closure (invoke it like a method).

**Note this does not add an action!**  It's just a utility closure/method available in every 
 controller.

Answer (score -2):

```
class BootStrap {
    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
        ...
    }
}
```