# Grails - Write method available in any controller

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security, metaprogramming

I'm quite new into groovy / grails world, so forgive for asking simple question. I'm pretty sure this can be done by meta-programming, that is injecting method into definition of grails controller class or so. Can anyone point me where should this injection be written (Bootstrap.groovy?). 
I'm trying to create currentUser() method with Spring-security-core plugin that I could use in any controller.

Comment: Is there a reason you'd rather do that than use `springSecurityService.currentUser`?

Comment: actually at time I asked quesiton, i was not aware of that property in springSecuirtyService bean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is answered in these two posts:

- [How can I add common actions to controllers without using inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821864/how-can-i-add-common-actions-to-controllers-without-using-inheritance)
- [Add methods to controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049418/add-methods-to-controllers)

However there are a couple of other approaches you might consider ...

You could just inject a "SecurityService" into controllers that need to know the current user and put "getCurrentUser" on that.

You could use a Grails filter to add "currentUser" to the params map available to all controllers. I like that approach as I usually use a filter to implement security anyway. The filter can also add it to all models prior to view rendering so all your views have access to it.